# Парсинг нескольких div с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Хочу спарсить несколько элементов с сайта и вывести в два разных `TextView` помогите пожалуйста, с примером

```
private class NewThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     String desc = null;
     try {
         Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru/").get();
         Elements description = document.select("a[class=list-link list-link_online]");

         desc = description.text();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return desc;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    
     but1.setText(result);
 }
```

Это вывод одного элемента `(div)` , а как вывести в `TextView` ещё один элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
private class NewThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<>;
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru/").get();
            Elements description = document.select("a[class=list-link list-link_online]");
            for (int i = 0; i < description.size(); i++) {
                desc.add(description.get(i).text())
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return desc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {    
        but1.setText(result.get(0));
        but2.setText(result.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Извени​ конечно , но не понял как этот код работает , зачем этот log?) but1.setText(result); это вывод одного элемента в мой textview , нужно второй элемент вывести в but2.setText(result);

Comment: @STUDMIX, log для примера, этот код показывает как можно парсить несколько элементов. внутри цикла можете сделать как вам угодно.

Comment: пример можешь привести , если не сложно с двумя TextView ?

Comment: @STUDMIX, обновил ответ, может не очень верно, пишу по памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за то что отозвался на помощь , только последний вопрос , например Elements one = document.select("a[class=one]"); и второй Elements two= document.select("a[class=two]"); с первым понятно , а второй как он выведит в Array